# Multiple EXE in Visual Studio solution - putting them all in a single output folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build-process

I'm probably just having a brain fart, but I have 2 library assembly projects in a solution, and 3 separate console EXEs which depend upon them - all in the same solution.  What's the best way to have the build put all the dlls and exes in a single location after the build (debug and release)?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg Please feel free to have a go at some of those questions I haven't accepted an answer on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the output location in the project properties. Usually my projects are arranged such as:

```
Root
  Applications
    Project A
  Libraries
    Project B
    Project C
```

And then to build to `..\..\Bin\` for both Debug and Release which puts Bin directly under Root. I do this because if not using the GAC libraries are copied local anyhow so I prefer to have them all in one place.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [PostBuild-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this.

You can easily have a whole toolchain in there.